# How do get ls to list directories with a trailing forward-slash?

Tags: bash, directory, ls

My shell is `bash`.  How can I get the output of `ls` to show directories with a trailing forward-slash?  When I do `ls` in `tcsh` it gives the desired output.  How can I get this to occur in `bash` without using any arguments?

eg.

```
bin/
lib/
src/
file1.txt
file2.txt
```

Comment: Your shell isn't relevant here... `man ls` then scroll down to `-p`

Comment: @don_crissti See my edit to the question.

Comment: @CJ7 - what is `type ls` output ? Maybe an alias ?

Comment: @don_crissti output is `ls is a tracked alias for /bin/ls`

Answer (score 22):

The simplest solution (as given already by @don_crissti in the comments) is:

```
ls -p
```

You can get a similar effect with:

```
ls -F
```

But that will add some other indicators as well:

> Append a character to each file name indicating the file type.
>        Also, for regular files that are executable, append `*`.  The file
>        type indicators are `/` for directories, `@` for symbolic links,
>        `|` for FIFOs, `=` for sockets, `>` for doors, and nothing for
>        regular files.

---

Of course, you can make the string `ls` execute `ls -p` on the command line with an alias:

```
alias ls='ls -p'
```

That is temporal and could be erased with `unalias ls`.
Probably your `tcsh` has an active alias in place.

Which you can do by placing the command in `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_aliases`.

Comment: That last bit caught my attention. I've never seen or heard of a `~/.bash_aliases` before; only `~/.bash_profile` and/or `~.bashrc`. Is it correct?

Comment: @tjt263 It is a common practice to place all aliases in a [special file sourced from bashrc](http://www.pkill-9.com/enabling-bash_aliases/). The contents [may vary depending on your needs](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1374947).

Comment: To keep colors: `alias ls='ls --color=auto -p'`

Answer (score 3):

You can use -F, e.g.

```
$ /bin/ls -F
-/                                 diesel_folks                 grub                     presidents             user_mailer/
0/                                 dmStaffing/                  HJJJH/                   prime_scenarios   
...
# I'm using /bin/ls to make sure I run my system ls 
# (I actually have it aliased to add options automatically normally)
#
# Just read about your no argument requirement
# So you too could alias it, i.e.

alias ls='ls -F'

# Put it in your `.bashrc` or `.bash_aliases` file
```

Comment: Do you know why `tcsh` is giving me desired output and `bash` isn't?

Comment: @CJ7 Because tcsh and bash use different configuration files (with different syntax). You presumably already have a similar alias in your `.cshrc`.

Comment: I tried making a `.bashrc` file in my home directory but it didn't work

Comment: @CJ7, did you restart your shell after making that change?

Answer (score 0):

Either

```
   ls --classify
```

Or:

```
   ls --indicator-style=slash
```

Explanation

```
   -F, --classify
          append indicator (one of */=>@|) to entries

   -p, --indicator-style=slash
          append / indicator to directories
```

The other answers more or less cover this, but I prefer GNU-style long options over BSD-style short options in Stack Overflow answers since they are more self-explanatory and learnable / "memorizable" / "internalizeable".

Answer (score 0):

On many systems like Ubuntu you can use the `l` command. It by default shows all of the directories with a forward slash. It actually is an alias for `ls -CF` (as you can find out by running `alias`). These kind of aliases are usually defined in `~/.bashrc` (in case you want to modify them or add additional ones).

Comment: Note that the resulting `ls -F` has been covered in existing answers. Other users may or may not have such an `l` alias...

Comment: It is an alternative that could be present.